# Doble for loop Python

Tags: python

Tengo las siguientes listas (ejemplo):

```
preguntas = ["pregunta1", "pregunta2", "pregunta3", "pregunta4"]
usuarios = ["Javier", "Esteban"]
```

Y busco un OUTPUT como esto:

```
"pregunta 1 para Javier"
"pregunta 2 para Esteban"
"pregunta 3 para Javier"
"pregunta 4 para Esteban"
```

Es decir, busco recorrer la lista `usuarios` dentro de la lista `preguntas` pero sin repetir las preguntas a los 2 usuarios, algo así como "intercalado"

**PD: Estas listas son incrementables, tanto la de usuarios como la de preguntas**

Comment: Creo que la parte que no se puede buscar en Google es por la que nos pagan en los trabajos, para resolver problemas. Te sugiero iterar las preguntas para imprimir una por una y luego utilizar un contador para decidir cuál usuario imprimir, este contador se debe de reiniciar cuando sea del tamaño del array de `usuarios` e incrementar en cada iteración. Si solo son dos usuarios puedes utilizar el indice de la iteración sobre preguntas y evaluar si es par para imprimir o "Javier" o "Esteban".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo logré hacer de la siguiente manera

```py
i = 0
for ind in preguntas:
    print(ind+" Para "+usuarios[i])
    if (i == 1):
        i = 0
    else:
        i = i+1
```

Definiremos la variable `i` para obtener los usuarios, esta se volverá a 0 cuando sea 1, ya que esa es la longitud de la lista `usuarios`

[image: Doble for loop Python]

Puedes hacer que este código sea flexible si la cantidad de usuarios es mayor, con `len()`

```py
i = 0
for ind in preguntas:
    print(ind+" Para "+usuarios[i])
    if (i == ((len(usuarios)) - 1)):
        i = 0
    else:
        i = i+1
```

El método `len()` te devolverá la longitud de la lista, como la estamos indexando como un clásico `array`, le restaremos 1 para prevenir errores de indexación

Comment: Muchas gracias!